# Move data files from c drive to drive windows 10

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, file-transfer, shortcuts

Windows 10: How can I move my data files from OS(C:) to DATA (D:) drive while ensuring all my shortcuts and references will work properly?

Comment: welcome at superuser. To help you we should know which shortcuts do you have (documents folder? links showing to current location?...)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways. If these are files in Documents or similar, it's probably safe to just right-click the Documents folder, open Properties, go to the Location tab, set a new location, and move the contents. Most things won't have hardcoded paths to the old location.

If you're concerned about things that do have such paths, though, there's a fix available! Windows 6.x (everything since Vista) supports directory symbolic links (symlinks, much like Linux). The main difference is that, by default, you must be Administrator to create them.

Let's say you want to move **"C:\Files\"** to **"D:\Files\"** without breaking paths like **"C:\Files\Stuff.docx"**. Here's what you do.

1. Make sure nothing has a file open in the original folder. If you must, sign out of your account and sign in as another user.
2. Open an Admin command prompt. We will be using a CMD built-in; the command won't work in Powershell.
3. Move the **"Files"** directory from C:\ to D:\ via `move C:\Files D:\Files` or your preferred alternate command (`robocopy`, whatever).
4. Ensure that the **"C:\Files"** directory is gone.
5. Create the symbolic link using the `mklink` command. Note that the order of the parameters is reversed from the Unix/Linux `ln` command: `mklink /D C:\Files D:\Files`. Don't forget to quote paths that have spaces in them!

There you go. You can now access files located in the new location (on drive D:) as though they're still at the old location, but it takes up almost no space on drive C:.